# How can I use the Tailwind CSS :group-first-of-type selector to target deeply nested elements?

Tags: html, tailwind-css

I'm trying to build a composble table in React and our use-case means I can't guarantee that there will be a `thead` that's part of the table. Because of this, I was hoping to target the first `tr` tag instead, to apply rounding to the first and last cells. The `group-first-of-type` selector seemed ideal for this, however it doesn't seem to work as I'd expect.

The selector `[&:first-of-type>td:first-of-type]:rounded-tl-md` will apply rounding to the first cell within the first `tr` within `tbody`, and I was hoping to switch this to `[&:group-first-of-type...]` to instead target the first `tr` within the table. See below:

```html
<table class="group">
 <!-- This may or may not be present, depending on usage. -->
 <thead>
   <tr class="[&:group-first-of-type>td:first-of-type]:rounded-tl-md">
     <td>My Cell</td>
     <td>My Other Cell</td>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr class="[&:group-first-of-type>td:first-of-type]:rounded-tl-md">
    <td>My Cell</td>
    <td>My Other Cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="[&:group-first-of-type>td:first-of-type]:rounded-tl-md">
    <td>My Cell</td>
    <td>My Other Cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="[&:group-first-of-type>td:first-of-type]:rounded-tl-md">
    <td>My Cell</td>
    <td>My Other Cell</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

This doesn't seem to work as I'd expect, and I'd prefer to keep this solution pure CSS if possible. (In my actual code, each HTML element is a separate component which gets consumed, which is why I'm needing to target tags this way).

Comment: What's the expected outcome? It's not clear to me... Can't you just round the `table`?

Comment: tailwind has turned into such a convoluted way to write css

Comment: @EduardoMottadeMoraes Unfortunately tables are the worst with CSS, so you can't just add 'rounded', you have to manually round the cells you need. Same with borders, it's incredibly annoying

Comment: @Sean I'll be honest, doing it in vanilla CSS might be the cleaner approach for this. It is a bit convoluted the nested tag targetting

Comment: You are using arbitrary variants, anything within the brackets are applied as is. it won't work with groups. you need something like: "group-[&_td]:bg-blue-400"